# CSS triangle and box shadow removing from a specific area

Tags: css, html

I have this code for making a box and to show a triangle attached to it on the left side :

CSS:

```
    .triangle-box{

     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     margin-top: 10px;
     border-top: 15px solid transparent;
     border-right: 15px solid #fff;
     border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
     float:left;

    }

    .triangle-box-content{

     background-color: white;
     -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     border-radius: 2px;
     border-bottom-color: #989898;
     height: 140px;
     width: 530px;
     float:left;
     text-align: left;
    }
```

Now I want to attach a shadow to this element as a whole. So I added this code in the triangle-box and triangle-box-content class :

```
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px #7a7a7a;
    -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 3px 5px #7a7a7a;
     box-shadow:  0 0 3px 5px #7a7a7a;
```

But this makes the shadow go around the box and the triangle making it look like two different divs. I want to remove the shadow from the region where the triangle and the box meet. Is there any way to do that?

HTML:

```
    <div class="triangle-box"></div>
    <div class="triangle-box-content"></div>
```

Comment: You need to add some HTML code, however I can guess that this seems to be impossible, although rendering some kind of solid border is tricky but possible while I don't think we can render the box shadow easily in this case.

Comment: I've added the HTML code now to show how I've used the classes. Can you think of any other method by which I can achieve this ?

Comment: You can easily do it with an svg.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never coded a single thing in svg so I don't know how to do it. There's nothing more in CSS which I can do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was a bit longer but I'll post it all the same.This technique rotates a pseudo element by 45 degrees with a bottom left shadow that sticks to the arrow.

**----UPDATE----**

This technique works without `.triangle-box`.

---

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/xfVeh/)**

HTML :

```
<div class="triangle-box-content"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.triangle-box-content:before, .triangle-box-content:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
}

.triangle-box-content:before {
    z-index:-1;
    top:13px;
    left:-10px;
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 0px #7a7a7a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 0px #7a7a7a;
    -o-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 0px #7a7a7a;
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 0px #7a7a7a;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.triangle-box-content {
    height: 140px;
    width: 530px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
    text-align: left;
    position:relative;
}
.triangle-box-content:after {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-2;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px #7a7a7a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px #7a7a7a;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px #7a7a7a;
}
```

Comment: Huh. You don't have any blur.

Comment: Wow, +1, this should be the best answer and accepted by the OP. In combination with `skew` transform, we can change the angle of the triangle (which is nearly 90 deg now) to something less than (such as 45 deg). I like this tweak.

Comment: @KingKing Thx + I just realised I could delete the arrow div with the same result :)

Comment: This works beautifully too. :) 
Thanks. 

One thing though: You've written "trianlge"-box-content instead of triangle-box-content which wasn't working for me at first. Just noticed the mistake, thought you should know.

Comment: @Cullen Glad I could help. In fact the class mistype came from the html you posted in your question ;) I'll update my answer

Comment: Oh!I didn't notice. I apologize. I'll edit my question too :)

Comment: @Cullen I just notice tha the content inside the box is hidden by the `:before` pseudo element. I corrected this by adding the shadow to the `:after` pseudo element see here : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/xfVeh/24/

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's still possible to achieve the effect you want. The idea is you can use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-element to create the diagonal edges of the triangle, apply some  rotate (45 deg and -45 deg) transform to them respectively in combination with a little trial and error. Here is the code:

```
.triangle-box{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  float:left; 
  /* note these are added to your original CSS */
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.triangle-box:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:17px;
  height:0px;    
  box-shadow: 0 -4px 3px 3px #7a7a7a;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) translateY(2px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  top:50%;
  position:absolute;    
}

.triangle-box:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:17px;
  height:0px;    
  box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 3px #7a7a7a;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) translateY(-2px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  top:50%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nmu8H/2/)

**NOTE**: I just used the `-webkit-` prefix for the `transform` property, you can add more prefixes for other browsers in actual implementation.

Here is how it looks like on my side:

[image]

Comment: It looks weirdly blurry…

Comment: @bjb568 maybe I've just tested in Opera, looks like you're using FireFox?

Comment: FF looks terrible, but that's just the vendor prefixes. It looks the same on Safari, Chrome, and Opera, with the blur of the box-shadow going into the triangle.

Comment: @King King: Yes I wanted this type of shadow around the element. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @bjb568 please see the image I posted, I can see just a little blur but I think it's acceptable. If it's much worse than that on your side, could you post some screen shot for me to see? thanks.

Comment: It looks the same here, it's perfectly acceptable, but I wonder why it's there…

Comment: @bjb568 I think it's because of the `spread` (which is 3px) in the `box-shadow` for the diagonal edges, maybe the blur `3px` also has its part in there.